# Novel where the protagonist flees a space station to escape the antagonist

Tags: story-identification, novel

The protagonist runs from a former lover/bad guy and needs to get off the space station, so she has a one night stand with the male protagonist who has a navigation implant.  They leave in a ship and arrive at a planet to help civilians settle down. Can't remember names of any characters. 1 word title I think. Written 2010s.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  There aren't a lot of details here; please [edit] your question to add everything else you can think of:  when you read it, names, how they were to help the people on the planet, why you call them "civilians" but not the protagonists, why she needed to flee, what the cover looked like, etc.

Comment: Updated best to my memory

Comment: If that's all you've got, that's all you've got.  We'll work on; we've managed with nearly this little before.

Comment: I've read it but can't remember the title. Girl had psychic powers but they were illegal for some reason. Ended up as part of a new colony project, which didn't go well ? Maybe?

Comment: I think so. It's driving me crazy not remembering

Comment: Anyone have any luck?

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add. For example, what language did you read it in? Where are you likely to have read it? Was it a long novel or a short novel? Were the events you've described basically the entire novel or just an incident that occurred in a larger story?

Comment: My thought is that this is superficially like Friday by Robert Heinlien. There are no psychic powers that I recall but there is an escape from a space station and something about a colony at the end but the question is way too vague for any kind of certainty.

Comment: Oops just noticed it is stated it was written 2010s. That rules out Heinlien then!